# latest package versions on python 3.9 not working with linux deployment

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Using pycharm for development and using python 3.9 and using the pandas (1.4.2) and numpy (1.22.3) latest version packages through requirements.txt (not providing any specific versions). It works fine in local machine with windows environment. The same code has been deployed as function app in linux environment and we are experiencing an issue when we trying to convert the datetime

```
pd.to_datetime(dataframe1['DOB'], errors='coerce').dt.tz_localize(tz=None)
```

The error message "Invalid Index Error:Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued index objects". When dataframe1['DOB'] contains NaT in any row.

Can fix this but, how come this is not happening in windows environment? Any insights will help to find the actual issue.

Comment: I think you should always putting on static the versions in your librairy. For example not do pandas>1.4.2 but pandas==1.4.2. Due to the fact that sometimes you will have dependencies  with other libraries which lead to an error like this.

Comment: we tried specific versions in requirement.txt like pandas==1.4.2 but, still having same issue in deployed server. Local its working fine even in this case.